# What is a local variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow has this API defined:

> `tf.local_variables()`
>
> Returns all variables created with `collection=[LOCAL_VARIABLES]`.
>
> Returns:
>
> A list of local Variable objects.

What exactly is a local variable in TensorFlow? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: see this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1045), there is a local variable that must be initialized before use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the same as regular variable, but it's in a different collection than default (`GraphKeys.VARIABLES`). That collection is used by saver to initialize the default list of variables to save, so having a `local` designation has an effect of not saving that variable by default.

I'm seeing only one place that uses it in the codebase, which is the `limit_epochs`

```
  with ops.name_scope(name, "limit_epochs", [tensor]) as name:
    zero64 = constant_op.constant(0, dtype=dtypes.int64)
    epochs = variables.Variable(
        zero64, name="epochs", trainable=False,
        collections=[ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
```

Comment: distributed tensorflow in distributed_replicated mode uses local variable.

Answer (score 27):

**Short answer**: a local variable in TF is any variable which was created with `collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]`. For example:

```
e = tf.Variable(6, name='var_e', collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
```

> LOCAL_VARIABLES: the subset of Variable objects that are local to each
>   machine. Usually used for temporarily variables, like counters. Note:
>   use tf.contrib.framework.local_variable to add to this collection.

They are usually not saved/restored to checkpoint and used for temporary or intermediate values.

---

**Long answer:** this was a source of confusion for me as well. In the beginning I thought that local variables mean the same thing as [local variable in almost any programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable), but it is not the same thing:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def some_func():
    z = tf.Variable(1, name='var_z')

a = tf.Variable(1, name='var_a')
b = tf.get_variable('var_b', 2)
with tf.name_scope('aaa'):
    c = tf.Variable(3, name='var_c')

with tf.variable_scope('bbb'):
    d = tf.Variable(3, name='var_d')

some_func()
some_func()

print [str(i.name) for i in tf.global_variables()]
print [str(i.name) for i in tf.local_variables()]
```

No matter what I tried, I always recieved only global variables:

```
['var_a:0', 'var_b:0', 'aaa/var_c:0', 'bbb/var_d:0', 'var_z:0', 'var_z_1:0']
[]
```

The documentation for [`tf.local_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/local_variables) have not provided a lot of details:

> Local variables - per process variables, usually not saved/restored to
>   checkpoint and used for temporary or intermediate values. For example,
>   they can be used as counters for metrics computation or number of
>   epochs this machine has read data. The local_variable() automatically
>   adds new variable to GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES. This convenience
>   function returns the contents of that collection.

---

But reading docs for the [**init**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) method in tf.Variable class, I found that while creating a variable, you can provide what kind of a variable do you want it to be by assigning a list of `collections`.

The list of possible collection elements is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys). So to create a local variable you need to do something like this. You will see it in the list of `local_variables`:

```
e = tf.Variable(6, name='var_e', collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
print [str(i.name) for i in tf.local_variables()]
```

Answer (score 11):

I think, here understanding of TensorFlow collections is required.

TensorFlow provides collections, which are named lists of tensors or other objects, such as `tf.Variable` instances.

Following are in-build collections:

```
tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES               #=> 'variables'                                                                                                                                                                                 
tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES                #=> 'local_variables'                                                                                                                                                                           
tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES                #=> 'model_variables'                                                                                                                                                                           
tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES            #=> 'trainable_variables'
```

In general, at the time of creation of a variable, it can be added to given collection by explicitly passing that collection as one of the collections passed to `collections` argument.

Theoretically, a variable can be in any combination of in-built or custom collections. But, in-build collections are used for particular purposes:

- [`tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#GLOBAL_VARIABLES):

  - The `Variable()` constructor or `get_variable()` automatically adds new variables to the graph collection `GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`, unless the `collections` argument is explicitly passed and doesn't include `GLOBAL_VARIABLE`.
  - By convention, these variables are shared across distributed environments (model variables are subset of these).
  - See [`tf.global_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables) for more details.
- [`tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):

  - When passed `trainable=True` (which is default behavior), the `Variable()` constructor and `get_variable()` automatically adds new variables to this graph collection. But of course, you can use `collections` argument to add a variab
    le to any desired collection.
  - By convention, these are the variables which will be trained by an optimizer.
  - See [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) for more details.
- [`tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#LOCAL_VARIABLES):

  - You can use [`tf.contrib.framework.local_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/local_variable) to add to this collection. But of course, you can use `collections` argument to add a variable to 
    any desired collection.
  - By convention, these are the variables that are local to each machine. They are per process variables, usually not saved/restored to checkpoint and used for temporary or intermediate values. For example, they can be used as counters
    for metrics computation or number of epochs this machine has read data.
  - See [`tf.local_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/local_variables) for more details.
- [`tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#MODEL_VARIABLES):

  - You can use [`tf.contrib.framework.model_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/model_variable) to add to this collection. But of course, you can use `collections` argument to add a variable to 
    any desired collection.
  - By convention, these are the variables that are used in the model for inference (feed forward).
  - See [`tf.model_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/model_variables) for more details.

You can also use your own collections. Any string is a valid collection name, and there is no need to explicitly create a collection. To add a variable (or any other object) to a collection after creating the variable, call [`tf.add_to_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection).

For example,

```
tf.__version__                                                            #=> '1.9.0'                                                                                                                                                       

# initializing using a Tensor                                                                                                                                                                                                               
my_variable01 = tf.get_variable("var01", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant([23, 42]))                                                                                                                                                 
# initializing using a convenient initializer                                                                                                                                                                                               
my_variable02 = tf.get_variable("var02", shape=[1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)                                                                                                                                 

my_variable03 = tf.get_variable("var03", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant([1, 2]), trainable=None)                                                                                                                                   
my_variable04 = tf.get_variable("var04", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant([3, 4]), trainable=False)                                                                                                                                  
my_variable05 = tf.get_variable("var05", shape=[1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.ones_initializer, trainable=True)                                                                                                                  

my_variable06 = tf.get_variable("var06", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant([5, 6]), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES], trainable=None)                                                                                       
my_variable07 = tf.get_variable("var07", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant([7, 8]), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES], trainable=True)                                                                                       

my_variable08 = tf.get_variable("var08", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant(1), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES], trainable=None)                                                                                            
my_variable09 = tf.get_variable("var09", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant(2), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES, tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "my_collectio
n"])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
my_variable10 = tf.get_variable("var10", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.constant(3), collections=["my_collection"], trainable=True)                                                                                                         

[var.name for var in tf.global_variables()]                               #=> ['var01:0', 'var02:0', 'var03:0', 'var04:0', 'var05:0', 'var09:0']                                                                                            
[var.name for var in tf.local_variables()]                                #=> ['var06:0', 'var07:0', 'var09:0']                                                                                                                             
[var.name for var in tf.trainable_variables()]                            #=> ['var01:0', 'var02:0', 'var05:0', 'var07:0', 'var09:0', 'var10:0']                                                                                            
[var.name for var in tf.model_variables()]                                #=> ['var08:0', 'var09:0']                                                                                                                                        
[var.name for var in tf.get_collection("trainable_variables")]            #=> ['var01:0', 'var02:0', 'var05:0', 'var07:0', 'var09:0', 'var10:0']                                                                                            
[var.name for var in tf.get_collection("my_collection")]                  #=> ['var09:0', 'var10:0']
```