# What is the difference between tf.initialize_all_variables() and tf.initialize_local_variables()?

Tags: tensorflow

I am reviewing the code in this example: [fully_connected_reader.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py)

I am confused with Line 147 and 148:

```
init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(),
                   tf.initialize_local_variables())
```

I don't know which variables are `all variables` and which are `local variables`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

`tf.initialize_all_variables()` is a shortcut to `tf.initialize_variables(tf.all_variables())`, `tf.initialize_local_variables()` is a shortcut to `tf.initialize_variables(tf.local_variables())`, which initializes variables in `GraphKeys.VARIABLES` and `GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLE` collections, respectively.

Variables in `GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES` collection are variables that are added to the graph, but not saved or restored ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L4009)).

[`tf.Variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) by default adds a new variable to `GraphKeys.VARIABLE` collection, which can be controlled by collections= argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I identify whether there is any local variables to initialize?

Comment: Should be able to graph them and print them out, this page has the reference you need https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys

Answer (score 5):

A local variable in TF is any variable which was created with `collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]`. For example:

```
e = tf.Variable(6, name='var_e', collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
```

> LOCAL_VARIABLES: the subset of Variable objects that are local to each
>   machine. Usually used for temporarily variables, like counters. Note:
>   use tf.contrib.framework.local_variable to add to this collection.

They are usually not saved/restored to checkpoint and used for temporary or intermediate values. For a more detailed answer, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602899/1090562).

A global variable is mostly every other variable initialized by you.

---

In a new version of TF you should use `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, `tf.local_variables_initializer()`, because the previous functions were deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

- GLOBAL_VARIABLES

Key to collect Variable objects that are global (shared across machines). Default collection for all variables, except local ones.

- LOCAL_VARIABLES

Key to collect local variables that are local to the machine and are not saved/restored.