# Why match_filenames_once function returns a local variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to understand the mechanism of tensorflow for reading images using queues. I was using the code found [here](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f), whom basic parts are:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once('D:/Dataset/*.jpg'))
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
image_name, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    print(image_tensor)
```

which in reality does nothing special. I was getting an error:

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue
>   '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested
>   1, current size 0)

which lead to search for missing images, wrong folder, wrong glob pattern etc until I discovered that tensorflow basically meant this:
"You need to initialize local variables also"!

Besides the fact that the code seemed to work in the original [gist](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f) with just this substitution:

```
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
```

instead of

```
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

in my code it does not work. It produces the same error. I guess it has changed the implementation of `initialize_all_variables()` with tensorflow development (I am using 1.3.0), since in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220201/tensorflow-tf-initialize-all-variables-vs-tf-initialize-local-variables) it mentions that it initialize local variables also.

So, the final conclusion I came with was that I should initialize local variables also. And my code worked. The error message is awfully misleading (which did not help at all) but anyway to the main part I am a bit confused why am I getting a local variable by `match_filenames_once`. In [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/match_filenames_once) there is no reference about this (I am not sure it should though).

Am I always going to get local from this `match_filenames_once`? Can I control it somehow?