# Uninitialized value error with tf.metrics.accuracy after both local and global initializers are called

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to put together a metric for coarse segmentation with on tensorflow for using with keras:

https://gist.github.com/DSLituiev/1adcc94b7e4e2b1861d39bbbc2db7307

I read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624648/tensorflow-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-value-in-variable-initialization), which suggests one must use local variable initializer, which I did, but I am still getting the exception:

```
Caused by op 'metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/AssignAdd', defined at:
  File "segm_test.py", line 96, in <module>
    metrics=[accuracy_per_channel],
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 784, in compile
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 924, in compile
    handle_metrics(output_metrics)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 921, in handle_metrics
    mask=masks[i])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 450, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "segm_test.py", line 89, in accuracy_per_channel
    return metric_per_channel_tf(x,y, nch=2, metric=tf.metrics.accuracy)
  File "segm_test.py", line 34, in metric_per_channel_tf
    _, prec_ = metric(label_channel, pred_channel)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py", line 411, in accuracy
    updates_collections, name or 'accuracy')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py", line 344, in mean
    update_total_op = state_ops.assign_add(total, math_ops.reduce_sum(values))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 239, in assign_add
    ref, value, use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 71, in assign_add
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/total
     [[Node: metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/AssignAdd = AssignAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/total"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/total, metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/Sum)]]
     [[Node: metrics/accuracy_per_channel/Mean/_43 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_858_metrics/accuracy_per_channel/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I tried to use `tf.get_variable('metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/total')` in an interactive debugger, but I am getting:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (metrics/accuracy_per_channel/accuracy/total) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

Which to my understanding implies that the variable does not exist at all?
Any tips how to proceed?